# Current iteration number in "do" command

Tags: procedural-programming, iteration

How can I obtain the current iteration number of the "Do" command? For example I want $N$ to be my iteration number in the following command:

```
Do[k = 3 i; Print[{N, k}], {i, 2, 6, 2}]
```

So I essentially want

```
Do[k = 3 i; Print[{N, k}], {i, 2, 6, 2}]
{1,6}
{2,12}
{3,18}
```

Comment: In this case, does it not make sense to say `Do[k=6i; Print[{i, k}] , {i, 1, 3}] `? But anyway, just set `count = 1` before the `Do` and then `Print[{count++, k}] ` inside...

Comment: `Do[k = 3 i; Print[{i/2, k}], {i, 2, 6, 2}]` or more simply `Do[Print[{i/2, 3 i}], {i, 2, 6, 2}]`

Comment: Just to state the obvious, though, have you considered `Table[{i, 6 i}, {i, 3}]` instead? Typically procedural loops are not the done thing in Mathematica.

Comment: Oh my example wasn't what I'm actually running, I only added it to clarify what I'm asking. I want a general method. Chris Degnen's answer below answers my question in a general method.

Comment: As a heads up, you cannot use `N` as a variable, it is a built-in function in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 0;
Do[k = 3 i; Print[{++x, k}], {i, 2, 6, 2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a progress indicator, which shows in real time how the calculations are progressing:

```
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[k/(3 20)]]

Table[Pause[0.1]; k = 3 i, {i, 1, 20, 1}]
```